# iPhone Passing A String From One Method To Another (Instance Variable?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have a value that is set during a method but it needs to be used in another method after.

I have set up an instance variable which is where i assume values can be used over all methods within that same instance however. I cannot seem to get it to load...

How is this done...

(if this sounds a little vague i'm sorry!)

Comment: sry i do not understand your question, you maybe want to use variable which can be used in whole class you should implement it as a class propertie or global variable and alocate it like this:[[something aloc]retain];

Answer (score 1):

If the instance variable is part of interface, then all the interface methods can use it.

```
@interface myInterface : NSObject
{
   // someInstanceVariable

}
-(void) initialize ;  // initialize someInstanceVariable
-(int) methodOne ;
-(float) methodTwo ;
@end
```

Both the method will be able to access the initialized instance variable.

Comment: ok well then i'm complete wrong. I need to use data from one method set it somewhere where it can be used for other methods.

Comment: Isn't the data setting method somewhere part of the interface ?

Comment: in the header i have declared "NSString *xmlString" as a property and synthesized it in the .m file. 

I then have a method that is getting a response string from a server and needs to store it in that variable so that other methods can use it.....? i hope thats a little more information for you... I might have to added i'm fairly new to this! :)

Answer (score 0):

just an example:
you have your class with your nsstring and two methods below:

```
-(void)setValue{
    self.xmlString = @"some string";
}

-(NSString*)getValue{
    NSLog([self xmlString]);
    return self.xmlString;
}
```

both methods can be used in the same instance as long as you define the variable as a property and synthesized it correctly.

then you can use

```
[yourInstance1 setValue:@"hello"];
[yourInstannce2 setValue:[yourInstance1 getValue]];
```

hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just declare that instance variable in .h file and then you can use it in any function of that class.